# limit x axis while keeping lines into offscreen

Tags: javascript, chart.js

We have upgraded chart.js from version 2 to 3 and now the following is not working. To make a single value, which should be displayed as a line, more readable, the value was simply displayed three times and only a section of the x axis was displayed. As a result, a straight line runs completely from left to right through the whole chart.

Here is an image of what it looked like in V2 vs. now in V3:
[Img-Description: left chart with version 2, all lines and areas go from left to right; right chart with version 3, the line starts left but end in the middle and the areas go down after the middle datapoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7hv6.png)

We are using the min/max attributes for the x scale. Any ideas?

This is my ChartConfiguration:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");

const configuration = { 
    "type": "line", 
    "data": {
    "labels": ["", "2015", ""],
    "datasets": [{
      "data": [8, 8, 8],
      "type": "line",
      "label": "Umsatzrentabilität",
      "borderColor": "#FF8F00",
      "backgroundColor": "#FF8F00",
      "fill": false,
      "yAxisID": "yRight",
    }, {
      "data": [18330.47727032784, 18330.47727032784, 18330.47727032784],
      "type": "bar",
      "label": "Gesamtleistung in TEUR",
      "backgroundColor": "rgba(0,152,100,0.8)",
      "hoverBackgroundColor": "#009864",
      "barPercentage": 0.5,
    }, {
      "data": [12, 12, 12],
      "type": "line",
      "label": "Branchenmitte von",
      "fill": "+1",
      "borderColor": "#dddddd",
      "backgroundColor": "rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.06)",
      "yAxisID": "yRight",
    }, {
      "data": [9, 9, 9],
      "type": "line",
      "label": "Branchenmitte bis",
      "fill": "-1",
      "borderColor": "#dddddd",
      "backgroundColor": "rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.06)",
      "yAxisID": "yRight",
    }],
  }, "options": {
    "maintainAspectRatio": false,
    "responsive": true,
    "scales": {
      "x": {
        "axis": "x",
        "grid": {
          "borderColor": "#bbbbbb",
          "color": "#f0f0f0",
          "display": true,
          "drawTicks": true,
          "drawBorder": true,
          "drawOnChartArea": true,
        },
        "min": "2015",
        "max": "2015",
        "type": "category",
        "bounds": "data",
        "id": "x",
        "position": "bottom",
      },
      "y": {
        "axis": "y",
        "title": {
          "align": "center",
          "display": true,
          "text": "Gesamtleistung in TEUR",
          "color": "#666",
        },
        "suggestedMax": 21996.572724393405,
        "suggestedMin": 0,
        "grid": {
          "borderColor": "#bbbbbb",
          "display": true,
          "drawBorder": true,
          "drawTicks": true,
          "drawOnChartArea": true,
        },
        "type": "linear",
        "id": "y",
        "position": "left",
      },
      "yRight": {
        "axis": "y",
        "type": "linear",
        "display": true,
        "position": "right",
        "title": {
          "align": "center",
          "display": true,
          "text": "Umsatzrentabilität (%)",
          "color": "#666",
        },
        "suggestedMax": 14.4,
        "suggestedMin": 0,
        "grid": {
          "borderColor": "#bbbbbb",
          "color": "#f0f0f0",
          "display": true,
          "drawBorder": true,
          "drawOnChartArea": false,
        },
        "id": "yRight",
      },
    },
  },
};


new Chart(ctx, configuration);
```

```css
#ctx {
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="ctx" />
```

Here is a fiddle with the current version: https://jsfiddle.net/Sue10bach/7q3n6wvb/

Comment: I kind of got it to show me the old version when I add another data point like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Sue10bach/gv6u7ojz/1/

I do not know why that works. Seems buggy like hell.